# How to call the same user input in different location in a print()

Tags: python

I am a beginner in python and i just want to get a number as user input and print the cube of it using a single line code. so i tried following line and it is asking for the number twice. is there any method to access the user input in different location in print()?

```
print("The cube of ", input("Please enter a Number"), "is", pow(int(input("Please enter a Number")), 3))
```

Comment: The best advice I can give for you is trying to put everything on one line of code all the time isn't a good idea

Comment: „I just want ... using a single line of code“ Why would you want to do that?

Comment: @Sayse Thanks a lot for your advice. highly appreciate it. But isn't there actually a way of doing this? since this is an exercise i got in a tutorial.

Comment: Are you actually required to print the initial input?

Comment: In Python 3.8 you technically could use walrus operator for that. But it's not a correct use because it's not readable (this current version is not readable either).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are getting the input prompt twice since you are using 'input' keyword twice.

The solution for that is, by getting input from user first and then printing cube:

```
num = int(input("Please enter a Number: "))
print("The cube of ", num, "is ", pow(num, 3))
```

This might come in handy for simple cases. But there are a lot more ways to get the desired output which helps a lot in complex cases.

**Using % Formatting**

```
print("The cube of %d is %d" %(num, pow(num, 3)))
```

**Using str.format**

```
print("The cube of {} is {}".format(num, pow(num,3)))
```

**Using f-strings**

```
print(f"The cube of {num} is {pow(num,3)}")
```

All the above methods will give you the same result.
You can read more about them in a simpler way [here](https://realpython.com/python-f-strings/).

If you really want to do this in a **single line of code**, you can use a lambda function with f-strings to achieve it like this:

```
print((lambda num: f"The cube of {num} is {pow(num,3)}")(int(input("Please enter a Number: "))))
```

All the best in learning and mastering Python.

Answer (score 4):

You can do like below:

```
print ((lambda x: x ** 3)(int(input("Please enter a Number"))))
```

Answer (score 3):

### If you don't assign `input()` value to a variable, you cannot retrieve it again.

#### Python 3.8

You can assign variables inside print statement.

```
print("The cube of " + (a := input("Please enter a Number")) + " is " + pow(a, 3))
```

#### Python < 3.8

You cannot do this in one statement only. Or maybe something like this:

```
print('{}\nThe cube of {} is {}'.format(exec('a=int(input("Please enter a Number"))'), a, pow(a, 3)))
```

Comment: @ALFA. In special cases (when you are using interpreter/console + immediately after input statement .. or with lambda functions) you can retrieve the value with '_'. However these are special cases and I agree with beer44 that your post should not have been down voted. It is a good answer.

Answer (score 2):

You could assign the input value to a variable like this:

```
def main():

    enteredNumber = input("Please enter a Number")
    print("The cube of ", enteredNumber, "is", pow(int(enteredNumber), 2)) 


if __name__== "__main__":
  main()
```

Comment: Yeah i got the point. But isn't there a way of doing this by using a single line of code?

Comment: Why the insistence on a single line? Is the single line a requirement? Use a semi-colon to separate statements: `num = int(input("Please enter a Number")); print(f"The cube of {num} is {pow(num,3)}"))`

Answer (score 2):

You can use assignment expressions to capture and pass-on the input:

```
print("The cube of ", (num := input("Please enter a Number")), "is", pow(int(num), 3))
```

Note that one would usually do that with multiple lines:

```
num = input("Please enter a Number")
print("The cube of ", num, "is", pow(int(num), 3))
```

Answer (score 2):

Since you are insisting on "single" line of code, my following suggestion is somewhat close. This will work on Python 3.x

```py
print(list(map(lambda x:x**3,[x for x in [int(input())]])))
```

Ideally you should split this into two lines.

**Edit inspired by Vijesh's answer**

Vijesh, in this post, has given a very succinct answer to accomplish the same. Below is the same code but omitting any use of variable name.

```py
print((lambda _ : _**3)(int(input())))
```